# Object null reference error MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nullreferenceexception

I have a viewmodel as:

```
public class AutoAdvert
{        
//
    public Condition condition { get; set; }
}
```

But when I access it in view it gives null reference error.

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.condition.Tyres)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.condition.Tyres)
</div>
```

Where I am paasing to view:

```
public ActionResult autoadvert()
        {
            AutoAdvert autoadvert = new AutoAdvert();

            return View(autoadvert);
        }
```

Comment: I'll assume your `condition` is `null`. What does the debugger say? Where do you set its value?

Comment: I use it in [HttpGet] action just to view the form fields.

Comment: Yes, but does the model being sent to your view actually contain an instantiated `condition`?

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: That means it has a `null` value. Please edit your post and include the code that shows where you send the model to the view.

Comment: Also include the constructor of `AutoAdvert` please.

Comment: Added the constructor and initialized the condition class object but still same exception

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35835/discussion-between-jeroen-vannevel-and-ali-shahzad)

Answer (score 1):

Your Condition is null. Add a Constructor to the autoadvert class and assign something to the variable.

```
public class AutoAdvert
{        
//
    public AutoAdvert(){
        Condition = New Condition();
    }
    public Condition condition { get; set; }
}
```

And you have to do the same thing in the Condition class to the Tyres if they are classes because the are null.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have forgotten to initialize the class `Condition` while populating the model class `AutoAdvert`